# Use of "the" - I think [the] tiger is one of the most impressive creatures

Tags: definite-article

> I think the tiger is one of the most impressive creatures.

I read this sentence [here](http://ieltsspeakingquestions.blogspot.com.au/2012/09/sample-answer-of-ielts-speaking-test.html) and wondering why "the" is used in the sentence. I think it is not any of [these situations](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/determiners-and-quantifiers/definite-article). I don't think the author is talking about that particular tiger either. Is this a mistake?

Comment: @Max Thank you, get it: used with a singular noun to indicate that it represents a whole species or class.

Comment: Yes, that sounds right.